# In SQL Server 2012 Failover Clustering, we are getting "The action 'Move' did not complete. Error Code: 0x80071398"

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

We have setup 2 VM Nodes for SQL Server 2012 Failover Clustering. The iSCSI drives are on our SAN. Cluster setup and SQL Server 2012 SP2 install succeeded without errors. Connecting to SQL Server from **Management Studio** remotely works to create a database for testing. When we try to move SQL Server from NODE1 to NODE2 we get this error:

**The action 'Move' did not complete.

Error Code: 0x80071398

The operation failed because either the specified cluster node is not the owner of the group, or the node is not a possible owner of the group.**

We get about the same results when we try to shut-down NODE1.

All of my resources appear to have both NODE1 and NODE2 as Possible Owners, except Other Resources: ... SQL Server. (or SQL Server Agent) If I right-click on it and select Properties then click the "Advanced Policies" tab I only see NODE1 available. How can we add NODE2 server here? Is that the final solution to this error? Thanks.

*Update:*
If we run Failover Cluster Manager on NODE2 and attempt to view Properties of SQL Server or SQL Server Agent in Other Resources we get an error.

**Cluster object 'SQL Server Agent' failed to load from cluster

An error occurred getting cluster properties and some of the property values may not be accurate.

Consider refreshing the view to reload the property values from the cluster.

Error Code: 0x800713d7

The specified node does not support a resource of this type. This may be due to version inconsistencies or due to the absence of the resource DLL on this node**

Answer (score 1):

I ran the SQL Server 2012 setup on NODE2.
Then selected "Add Node to a SQL Server Failover Cluster"

This version of SQL Server does not copy the binaries to all clustered nodes.

Cured all of the problems above.

Comment: No version of SQL Server ever did ;)